# HighCharts in Laravel Errors

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, charts

Hello Everyone i have this trouble now with my laravel project i am trying to add pie chart from highcharts, i added the javascrips in home.blade.

But a got this issue and i need to resolve, look at this.

The Error :

> json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given

The Code:

Controller:

```
 $decisiones = Visita::all();

        $puntos = [];

        foreach($decisiones as $decision )
        {

            $puntos = ['name' => $decision['registrante'], 'y' => $decision['id']]; 
        }

 return view('Reportes.ReporteTomaDecision', ["data" => json_decode($puntos)]);
```

the View

```
data: <?= $data ?>
```

this my variable from controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks more like you have to return json in the view so you have to encode the data.

Then try this:

```
$decisiones = Visita::all();
$puntos = [];

foreach ($decisiones as $decision) {

    $puntos = ['name' => $decision['registrante'], 'y' => $decision['id']]; 
}

return view('Reportes.ReporteTomaDecision', ["data" => json_encode($puntos)]);
```

view:

```
<?= $data ?>
```

Comment: it works, show  nothing but at least, no logical errors. i think maybe might be something with the view the reason that cant show the Pie, but at least can conect with the view.

Comment: I never use Laravel, so I don't know about the kind of the view and how variables are noted there. plain php might be wrong.

Comment: it was the links i forgot import the scripts links.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't shown in your question ;-) Thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```html
 $decisiones = Visita::all();

        $puntos = [];

        foreach($decisiones as $decision )
        {

            $puntos[] = ['name' => $decision['registrante'], 'y' => $decision['id']]; 
        }

$data = json_encode($puntos);

 return view('Reportes.ReporteTomaDecision', compact($data)]);
 
 
 go to ReporteTomaDecision blade 
 
 {{$data}}
```

Comment: he never has json to decode, `$puntos` is an array

Comment: Ok i will try cause with the last answer it didnt work :(.